# Firebase: site not updated after doing firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I just migrated my Firebase project to the new console (now it is firebase.google.com)

But after running firebase deploy, I found that the files are not updated, it says

```
starting release process (may take several minutes)...

✔ Deploy complete!
```

but nothing changed on my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it took some time for the first deployment after migration.

Comment: I guess, it takes some time to reflect the changes. It did, in my case.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you're building any new changes you've made, so if you have an angular 2 application and are using the cli type **ng build** then **firebase deploy**